# Trouble with setInterval in an object's method

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I can't figure out why when I call the reset method of the object, the timer is still null. I simplified version of my object is below, followed by the jQuery that constructs a new object and runs the code. See UPPERCASE comments for my specific question points. Thanks!

```
    var countdownTimer = {
        // Default vars
        milliseconds: 120000,
        interval: 1000, 
        timer: false,

        /* ... stuff ... */
        countdown: function () {
            var root = this;
            var originalTime = root.milliseconds;
            /* ... stuff */
            // IN MY MIND THIS NEXT LINE SETS THE INSTANCE OF THIS OBJECT'S TIMER PROPERTY TO THE setIterval's ID.  BUT DOESN'T SEEM TO BE CORRECT. WHY?
            root.timer = setInterval(function () {
                if (root.milliseconds < 1) {
                    clearInterval(root.timer); // THIS LINE SEEMS TO WORK
                    root.countdownComplete(); // callback function
                    return false;
                }
                root.milliseconds = root.milliseconds - root.interval;

                /* .... stuff ... */
            }, root.interval);
        },
        start: function (ms) {
            if (ms) {
                this.milliseconds = ms;
            }
            if(this.timer) {
                clearInterval(this.timer);  // NOT SURE IF THIS WORKS OR NOT
            }
            this.countdown();
        },
        reset: function (ms) {
            var root = this;
            if(root.timer) {
                clearInterval(root.timer); // THIS DOES NOT WORK
            } else {
                console.log('timer not exist!!!!'); // ALWAYS END UP HERE. WHY?
            }
            /* .... stuff ... */
        },
        countdownComplete: function() {  }

    };

// Setting up click events to create instances of the countdownTimer
$(function () {
    var thisPageCountdown = 4000;

    $('[data-countdown]').on('click', '[data-countdown-start], [data-countdown-reset]', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $wrap = $this.closest('[data-countdown]');
        // create instance of countdownTimer
        var myCountdown = Object.create(countdownTimer);

        if ($this.is('[data-countdown-start]')) {
            $this.hide();
            $('[data-countdown-reset]', $wrap).css('display', 'block');
            myCountdown.$wrap = $wrap;
            myCountdown.start(thisPageCountdown);
            // myCountdown.countdownComplete = function() {
            //  alert("Updated Callback!");
            // };
        } 

        if ($this.is('[data-countdown-reset')) {
            $this.hide();
            $('[data-countdown-start]', $wrap).css('display', 'block');

            // RESET CALLED HERE BUT DOESN'T WORK RIGHT. SAYS myCountdown.timer IS STILL null. WHY?
            myCountdown.reset(thisPageCountdown); 
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `var myCountdown = Object.create(countdownTimer);` inside of your click function callback you are scoping it only to that callback and once the callback has executed it is garbage collected. You need to only create one instance of the `countdownTimer`, and it should be outside of your click event handler.

```
var thisPageCountdown = 4000;
// create instance of countdownTimer
var myCountdown = Object.create(countdownTimer);

$('[data-countdown]').on('click', '[data-countdown-start], [data-countdown-reset]', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $wrap = $this.closest('[data-countdown]');
```

Comment: This makes sense to me, but how then would I have two timers on the screen at once acting independently?

Comment: @Ben - Is start used multiple times in a row before a reset is used?

Comment: each time countdownTimer.start is used it is supposed to clear the interval and then countdownTimer.start calls countdownTimer.countdown which then creates a new setInterval.  The start action is called by clicking a start button. It can not be clicked again (it's hidden) until the user clicks on a reset button which calls countdownTimer.reset

Comment: @Ben - So that seems like you would never have more than one timer, unless I am missing something.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  It is possible that there would be two or more timers on the screen. Each with its own set of start and reset buttons.

Comment: @Ben - Ah, in that case you would need to come up with a scenario where the state of the element was kept in order to relate it to its current timer.

Comment: so you mean like using a data-interval attribute to the buttons that holds the value of the setInterval ?   Or would it hold the name of the object?  I'm a little confused.

Comment: @Ben - There would be a large amount of ways to accomplish it :) Using a data attribute or the jquery data object would be one way to track the element's state.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** You can fix your issue by avoiding use of the keyword `this` in static methods.

When you use the keyword `this` in a static javascript method, it refers to the item before the last dot from the call point. Example:

```
foo.bar(); // inside, this will refer to foo
foo.bar.foobar(); //inside, this will refer to foo.bar
var a = foo.bar.foobar();
a(); //this will refer to either null or window - oops
```

To prevent this behavior, you should always use the fully qualified name reference in static methods instead of relying on the `this` keyword.

Example from above:

```
reset: function (ms) {
  //var root = this; // don't do this
  if(countdownTimer.timer) {
    clearInterval(countdownTimer.timer); 
  } else {
    console.log('timer not exist!!!!'); 
  }
  /* .... stuff ... */
}
```

Comment: Same failed result using this code. I think because In this example countodwnTimer would be the original object which the myCountdown object was based on, and not the actual object that was created (myCoundown).  Also I thought using the `var root = this` was considered good practice per this: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javascript-the-good/9780596517748/ch04s03.html